# Does "pointerVariable ==" mean something different from "pointerVariable="?

Tags: c++

For example:

```
node * curr;
if(curr = NULL)
```

vs

```
node * curr;
if(curr == NULL)
```

What do each of these things mean?

Comment: The first assigns NULL to the the pointer `curr` and then tests if `curr` is non-NULL.  The second tests whether `curr` is NULL.  (Usually when you see a single `=` in an `if` statement it's a bug.)

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/1607442)

Comment: Your question is missing something in a format similar to `"I know that ... means ..., but in this context .... I looked online and found ..., but ..."`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are different.

The first example uses the assignment operator (`=`) and assigns `NULL` to`curr`, and then its value is used as the condition for the `if`. Since it's `NULL`, and `NULL` is considered false when it comes to conditions, execution will never enter the block. This is most likely a bug and at least GCC and Clang will emit a warning for it.

The second one uses the comparison operator (`==`) to compare `curr` to `NULL`. If `curr` is equal to `NULL`, execution will enter the block. `curr` remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

In any C language, or many derived from C, a single = is assignment and double == is equality test.

`if ( curr = NULL )` assigns NULL to curr then tests if true or false. It is always false.

`if ( curr == NULL)` tests if curr is NULL and does not change it.

As it is all too easy to drop an "=" converting equality tests to an assignment I have started putting the constant on the left:  `NULL == curr`. If I ever drop an equal it becomes `NULL = curr`, which is invalid and the compiler throws a fatal error. Yes, high compiler checks can catch such drops, but my way guarantees compiler failures.

Comment: Good ol' [Yoda conditions](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/).